# Unexpected behavior in mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I tested these mod_rewrite's

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/$ /index.php?req=$1
```

rules at http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

and got exactly the results I needed, as you may see in this image:

[image]

but when I run the very same URL in my server I receive a 404 error:

[image]

Any clues about why is this happening?

Comment: your rewrite says it must end with a /, in your test it does, in your browser it doesn't - therefore it doesn't match and redirect!

Comment: Yeah! One of those simple things that we just do NOT see!